# Вопрос по полосе прокрутки - ScrollView и setScrollY

Tags: android, eclipse, прокрутка

Здравствуйте.
Есть

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"
            android:onClick="onClick10" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
            android:padding="10dip">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/about_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="1856dp"
                android:text="@string/about_text" />

        </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

и

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.about);
    openFile(FILENAME);
    SV = (ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    SV2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.about_content);
    setScrolY(345);
}
public void setScrolY(int nnn) {
    SV.setScrollY(nnn);
}
```

Нужно что бы при открытии активности текст в `ScrollView` не помещающийся в экран(Книга), переходил по Y-ку в определенное место,но больше чем примерно на 30 пикселей не переходит, хотя `getScrollY` работает корректно. И этот же `setScroll(nnn)`; тоже работает корректно если делать из кнопки

```
public void onClick10(View v) {
    SV.setScrollY(nnn);
}
```

Помогите сделать переход по тексту при открытии активности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

подозреваю, это должно помочь

```
SV.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SV.setScrollY(200);
    }
});
```

Comment: Всё заработало,отлично!!!Огромное спасибо!!!